# Is it possible to use network sockets in a DDK project?

Tags: windows, networking, driver, wdk

Since WinSock and other socket C libraries are not available in DDK project, what should I use then ? I need to communicate in TCP protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the Winsock Kernel (WSK) API.  You can find sample code in src\network\wsk\echosrv.